# Calculate net salary given the gross salary in different countries

Tags: finance

I'm looking for a program or web application that can calculate the net salary given the gross salary in different countries.

http://calculatenetsalary.com/ is decent but tax data is a bit old, many countries are missing and one has to compute one country at a time (I would prefer to see the net salary for all countries at once).

Any OS, license and price are fine.